# How can I force torch.jit.trace to compule my module by ignoring hooks?

Tags: pytorch

I have a module containing hook, and I would like to compile it with jit's trace:

```py
compiled_model = torch.jit.trace(model,  torch.rand(1, 3, 256, 256))
```

But I get the error:

```
ValueError: Modules that have hooks assigned can't be compiled
```

How can I force trace to ignore the hooks ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to bypass trace's check, you can recursively remove all the hooks from your model.

This can be done by iterating over the children:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
def remove_hooks(model):
    model._backward_hooks = OrderedDict()
    model._forward_hooks = OrderedDict()
    model._forward_pre_hooks = OrderedDict()
    for child in model.children():
        remove_hooks(child)
```

Then you can force the compilation:

```py
remove_hooks(model)
compiled_model = torch.jit.trace(model,  torch.rand(1, 3, 256, 256))
```

But if the hook are actually doing real work and you want to keep them in the trace (which was my case) you can just comment torch's raise in `torch/jit/__init__.py` the lines :

```py
if orig._backward_hooks or orig._forward_hooks or orig._forward_pre_hooks:
    raise ValueError("Modules that have hooks assigned can't be compiled")
```

It worked for me and I managed to compile a fastai model.